# Vim slowdown when browsing with netrw

Tags: netrw, performance

Sometimes there are several second long slowdowns when browsing Clojure source code in a Git repo via Vim's netrw. My Vim version is 7.4.865.

I do have a couple of plugins that must have caused this. How do i most efficiently identify the culprit without resorting to disabling plugins one-by-one (or binary-tree wise)? Is there some sort of logging/verbose mode/etc. i could turn on to see what function takes so much time?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the best way to debug your plugins as far as I know is to disable them one by one. Also netrw is considered by a lot of vimmers as old and buggy you might be interested in using another explorer plugin :-)